# "fake path" issue using multer+angular 6

Tags: javascript, typescript, cors, angular6, multer

I spend the last 3 days to fix the problem , but i didnt figure out yet the issue.

Angular CLI: 6.0.8

Node: 8.11.2

OS: win32 x64

Angular: 6.0.6

multer. 1.3.1

**my code at "childApi" using multer staff  :**

```
var store = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '.' + file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: store , }).single('file');

router.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log ('not working well')
        }
        //do all database record saving activity
        return res.json({ originalname: req.file.originalname, uploadname: req.file.filename });
    });
});
```

**my code at "add-child" component using simple code  :**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { Child } from '../../models/child';
import { ChildService } from '../../services/child.service';
import {FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';

const uri = 'http://localhost:3000/childApi/upload';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-child',
  templateUrl: './add-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-child.component.css']
})

export class AddChildComponent implements OnInit {
    newChild = new Child;
    uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: uri });
    attachmentList: any = [];


  constructor(private childService: ChildService, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private router: Router, 
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddChildComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { 


      this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {
          this.attachmentList.push(JSON.parse(response));
      };
    }
```

---

The problem is that after  I  upload the file to the folder "uploads"
,I want to display my new photo on the screen.

**The console give me this error :**

GET unsafe:C:\fakepath\child+thinking.jpg 0 ()

If someone help its will be amazing.

Thanks...

Comment: the problem solved :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out what to do , I just put this sentences inside my code at "add-child" component using :

```
this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {
        this.newChild.user_img = JSON.parse(response).uploadname;
        this.attachmentList.push(JSON.parse(response));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your post that you have doing a model named child inside your project so if you have can I take a look on it I will be grateful because I'm doing the same task except still getting the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/file/upload' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
core.js:1449 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at FileUploader.UploadFileComponent.uploader.onCompleteItem (upload-file.component.ts:27)
    at FileUploader.push../node_modules/ng2-file-upload/file-upload/file-uploader.class.js.FileUploader._onCompleteItem (file-uploader.class.js:199)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYerror] (file-uploader.class.js:268)`
javascript html typescript angular6 multer
```